# Confused about inheritance in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, base-class

I have a base class looking like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
}
```

Classes that inherit this:

```
public class ABC : BaseController {
   public void Create(string a, string b) {
      var Meta = new Meta();
      Meta.Title = "test";
   }
}

public class DEF : BaseController {
   public void Create(string a, string b, string c) {
      var Meta = new Meta();
      Meta.Title = "job";
   }
}
```

Every one of the classes that inherits from BaseController needs to create an instance of Meta();

Is there some way that I could move this creation from the classes ABC & DEF into the base controller? Note that some of the methods in classes ABC, DEF etc have different number of arguments.

One idea I had for this was to do the following in the BaseController:

```
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (Meta == null) { Meta = new Meta(); }
    }
```

Is this a valid thing to do. Also if I did this in the BaseController then would the field Meta be available in classes that inherit from the BaseController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably do it like below. And yes, you can access meta if you define it protected (or public of course).

```
public class BaseController : Controller { 
   protected Meta meta;

   public void Create() { 
      meta = new Meta(); 
   } 
}

public class ABC : BaseController { 
   public void Create(string a, string b) { 
      base.Create();
   } 
} 

public class DEF : BaseController { 
   public void Create(string a, string b, string c) { 
      base.Create();
   } 
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but var a would conflict with the a parameter in the Create method of BaseController.

Comment: I didn't modify the code there, just merged this code line from two places just like it exists. That's why i didn't add protected variables etc.

Comment: I just changed the original, renamed a to something else and added the setting of a Title. Can you have a look. Would it be advisable to add protected and how would this help?

Comment: I used lowercase meta as variable to differ from the type. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Emir. I need to get access to the variable meta to add things to it in the ABC and DEF classes. Can I do that also. Would that require it not to be protected?

Comment: you can access that variable just like any other variables in your class. protected means protected from direct access from outside. but classes which inherit that class can access protected members.

Comment: @EmirAkaydın you need to remove the `var` declaration.  Right now it's assigning a local variable

Comment: @Davy8: You are right. Removed it. Those misatakes caused by modifying from the orginal code and not trying to compile the code. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
    protected Meta Meta { get; set; }
    protected void Create()
    {
        if (Meta == null) { Meta = new Meta(); }
    }
}

public class ABC : BaseController {
   public void Create(string a, string b) {
      base.Create();
   }
}

public class DEF : BaseController {
   public void Create(string a, string b, string c) {
      base.Create();
   }
}
```

If you only want access to Meta from the base class then make meta `private`.  If you want access to Meta only from things that inherit from the base class then you make it `protected`.  If you want anything that creates an instance of ABC or DEF to have access to Meta too then make it `public`.